# Console login not working

Tags: console

So I'm having some issues with Ubuntu that require console login. My screen will show up saying: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS excite-frags (my username) tty1
excite-frags login:
So whatever I try, with the right password, always ends up in a Login Incorrect error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first prompt of `login:` is asking for your username. It will then prompt you for the password.

That should allow you to login